# Randomize the sub mesh rendered on a Game Object at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a mesh that has multiple elements (like body, head and so on).

I have saved it as prefab, showing certain elements and hiding others (basically in the editor hierarchy of the mesh, I uncheck the "skinned mesh renderer", for what I want to hide); so when I instantiate the prefab, it always look the same (expected of course).

Now, I would like to randomize the elements displayed, and improve visual variety; although I have requirements, for example:

- 1 body and one head
- 1 set of hair
- 1 set of weapons (axe or sword and shield or staff...)

and so on; to give an idea.

How should I deal with this issue? I thought to assign each element of the mesh to a script, with public variables and attach it to the prefab; and then in that script, create rules to display only what I need, while the rest has the skinned mesh renderer disabled.

This imply adding the various elements in the hierarchy of the mesh, in dictionaries, so I can pick at random only one element for each of the categories (clothing, body, weapon, head and so on).

```
public class CreateRandomGuy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject body;
    public GameObject body2;
    public GameObject body3;
    public GameObject weapon1;
    public GameObject weapon2;

    List<GameObject> bodies; 
    List<GameObject> weapons;

    public void RandomizeGuy()
    {

         bodies = new List<GameObject>(){
             body1,
             body2,
             body3
         };
         weapons = new List<GameObject>(){
             weapon1,
             weapon2
         };

         body_to_show = rnd.next(0,2);
         weapon_to_show = rnd.next(0,1);

         // instantiate mesh with ResourceLoad
         GameObject randomguy = Instantiate(Resources.Load("theguy"));
         // enable the skinned mesh rendered for the random element
         bodies[body_to_show].GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>.Enable(true);
         weapons[weapon_to_show].GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>.Enable(true);

    }

}
```

On paper it works, before implement it I would like to look at alternatives, that may (surely?) be better than my approach.

Comment: why dont you have it derive from monobehaviour so you can assign your stuff directly to the lists from inspector (saves a lot of typing). also you could have your "submeshes" be individual gameobjects aswell, i image to have a better overview in the hierarchy then. but besides that, i dont see why it shouldnt be working ...

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the monobehaviour derived. I did notice that the editor accept also skinnedmeshrenderer directly; so dragging on the slot the gameobject containing the mesh, it takes it directly, which is a ton of code saved.

Comment: FYI I've always found the "submesh" feature sort of weird / pointless / confusing in Unity.  There's no need for it.  You're inevitably better to - very simply - just have different game objects.  I can see no development or performance advantages whatsoever to using submeshes.

Comment: @newbiez what i meant is, you can just make your lists public and theyll show up in the inspector. theres absolutely no need to have body1..3 ...

Comment: Sorry @yes, now I get what you meant before. Make no sense to code the list, when I can just populate it from the editor.

Comment: @JoeBlow, how do you actually "detach" a mesh that is skinned and rigged, from the parent, to create a standalone game object? I did try to take them out of the hierarchy and they go crazy all over (in some case they just won't respond anymore, unless they are children of the main mesh)

Comment: i don't know!  i've never done that; sorry i didn't especially notice you were dealing with skinned-boned models. (I just saw "mesh" and made the general comment "forget about this submesh stuff!")

Comment: TBC there's this guy .. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SkinnedMeshRenderer.BakeMesh.html

Comment: and a useful couple notes on it .. http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/transform-problem-with-vertex-positions-from-skinnedmeshrenderer-bakemesh.158312/

Comment: Thanks @JoeBlow; this is the first time that I work with skinned mesh in Unity; I thought that it is easier to handle just one mesh with a bunch of different mesh attached to it, so I can swap traits on each NPC, instead than create variants and instantiate the whole thing every time.

Comment: Interesting, so you can bake the skinned mesh, although it seems that the calculations are done also when the mesh is not visible....I fear that this may impact performances since I have a ton of NPC running around the scene; I have to investigate further.